# How to count total number of childs of current user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How can I get the child count of current user, e.g. current user's email is uzahid231@gmail.com so I have to get 1 as other products are from different users

Comment: Please share some code. What have you tried. What is the structure of your db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Products");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- I highly recommend searching for your use-case going forward, as there is a lot of information about this alreaduy: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+realtime+database+get+count+of+nodes+for+condition
- This code reads all matching child nodes, as Firebase has no built-in aggregation operation. If you're reading just the nodes for the current user that is probably not too bad, but whenever you do something like this consider how much data you're reading for how many users. At some point it'll be more efficient to simply store the count in the database, and update that whenever writing products. For more on this, see some of the answers in the search results above.

Answer (score 1):

Using the official documentation you should be able to translate this to the language of your needs.

Done in swift:

```
// Get reference to the DB
let ref = db.collection("Products")

// Query for the email field
let query = ref.whereField("email", isEqualTo: "uzahid231@gmail.com").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            querySnapshot!.documents.count // <-- Number of documents
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                // all the documents that satisfied the query
            }
        }


}
```

Here is the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: That code is for Cloud Firestore, but from the screenshot in the question it seems OP uses Realtime Database.